# vbscript windows xp warning message based on date

Tags: vbscript, windows-xp, warnings, datemodified

I would like windows XP to have a running script that checks the "date modified" of files as they are opened and give the user a warning message if the date matches between 1/1/11 to 7/15/14. The files might have no extension, a .pm5 extension, a .nc extension or a .drl extension. I'm not concerned with any other file extensions.

Ive found help how to create a .vbs windows message box, I found help how to check for date modified but not how to check any file with listed extension being opened and give a warning message.

thank you all

Answer (score 0):

There is no feature for this in script. So you need a vb.net program using a filewatcher object. You can make vb.net programs on your computer with notepad. See here for the principal http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adcae113-4758-481a-a367-60d5d14d97d6/this-is-how-to-turn-vbs-and-js-files-into-exe-files-from-the-command-line-without-third-party-tools?forum=scripting.

You could turn on auditing of files, set the containing folders to audit files (note two steps to audit something). An security event will be written to event log.

Task Scheduler can run tasks based on event log messages.

Comment: auditpol /set /subcategory:"file system" turns on auditing. Then set what is to be audited.